# Invalid .ipa file: Info.plist couldn't be read

Tags: ipa, payload

Iphone app was created using an online platform which no longer exists. Probably a year ago. I am trying to upload to https://www.diawi.com/ now, so that the app can still be used in some fashion.

I originally received an error stating "Error with Payload Directory" and moved the .app folder into a folder called "Payload" and now it seems not be able to find the Info.plist file. Any assistance? I am a bit out of date in my app experience.

App.ipa is located at http://beveragedist.com/app/Payload.ipa 
for anyone who can help me troubleshoot the internal file structure.